# Are the ID in celery's message format per task or per call of a task?

Tags: python, protocols, celery

I see in the Celery protocol Docs (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html) that there is an ID in the message. It says that it is the "Unique id of the task (UUID)"

It this really supposed to be the same every time a task is called? Or is it an ID of the specific call of a task?

In other words if I call the task "dod.airforce.launch_the_nukes" twice, will the 2 calls have the same UUID, of different ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every task call generates a new uuid if task_id argument is not used.

```
$ python tasks.py call tasks.add --args='[1,2]'
96307fbd-81be-4e1d-964b-fb11425c60db
$ python tasks.py call tasks.add --args='[1,2]'
d4d250e0-5f6c-464d-96bf-f84435e0f4d6
```